# Can conditional formatting distinguish values and formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm having an Excel sheet, mentioning the status of a task, with following columns:

```
Task | ID | First answer date | Workaround date | Solved date | Scheduled date | Still_Open
```

The column `Still_Open` contains the following formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B:B);"";AND(ISBLANK(E:E);ISBLANK(F:F);ISBLANK(G:G)))
```

The result of this can by `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

I've applied a conditional formatting in order to clearly see the `TRUE` cases, but now there are some cases where I need to replace the formula by a fix value `TRUE`.

The conditional formatting will show both `TRUE` values (the fix values and the formula results) in the same, which I don't like.

Is there a way to distinguish fix values from formulas, using conditional formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two distinct Conditional Formatting formulas:

To format cells with fixed TRUE/FALSE use:

```
=AND(A1=TRUE,ISNA(FORMULATEXT(A1)))
```

To format values produced by formula use:

```
=AND(A1=TRUE,NOT(ISNA(FORMULATEXT(A1))))
```

Repeat the same for false if you want distinct formatting for FALSE values

Adjust A1 reference accordingly...